# ical feed doesn't work after adding mysql

Tags: php, mysql, icalendar

I'm building a ical feed for my website. This works perfectly until I try to make it dynamic with Mysql.

**Context**
The code I want to replicate is on the website of Steve Thomas.

This code works perfectly fine (source: http://joeyclz119.119.axc.nl/test/):

```
$title =  "title";
$output .= "BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:$title UID:15 STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20170220T214129Z DTEND:20170220T224129ZLAST-MODIFIED:20160509T031500Z LOCATION:home END:VEVENT\n ";
```

But when I call the mysql it doesn't work anymore (source: http://joeyclz119.119.axc.nl/test/two):

```
foreach ($query->result() as $appointment):
$title =  $appointment->title ;    
$output .= "BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:$title UID:15 STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20170220T214129Z DTEND:20170220T224129ZLAST-MODIFIED:20160509T031500Z LOCATION:home END:VEVENT\n ";
endforeach;
```

The strange thing is that this code doesn't give any error. So it opens perfectly fine in the web browser. However, when opening this as a feed in iCal (my Apple calendar), all events within the for loop don't work anymore. And they only don't work whenever "$appointment->title ;" is called (so when only the foreach loop is called, the code still works). Also, other events which are not within the for loop are still visible in iCal.

Note: the whole mysql query is called in both situations. Only when adding $appointment->title (even without the "$title =") the code breaks down.

**Question** Why doesn't the code work anymore whenever I call the Mysql variable? Does it change the format of the html file?

Comment: Dump your output and examine it. Maybe it's not what you think it is.

Comment: what do you mean by dump your output? I have examined the source code, and the two scripts looked exactly the same.

Comment: How can I dump my output?

Comment: After you've finished creating your `$output`, use `echo $output` or `var_dump($output)` and look at the finished creation. See if the data looks like it should.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your database code isn't working, but your iCalendar syntax is incorrect.  Each property must be separated by a line break.

```
$output .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\nSUMMARY:$title\r\nUID:15\r\nSTATUS:CONFIRMED\r\nDTSTART:20170220T214129Z\r\nDTEND:20170220T224129Z\r\nLAST-MODIFIED:20160509T031500Z\r\nLOCATION:home\r\nEND:VEVENT\n ";
```